# Titanium studio debugging wrong line

Tags: titanium

When I set break points the debugger breaks at the wrong line. I then set my break points within the 'loaded scripts', the debugger trace indicates that it is at the correct line (of the loaded scripts) but it opens the source files to the wrong point in the code.
This had made debugging next to impossible. I am using OSX yosemite and titanium studio 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Alloy?

If so, then when you set debug points you will have to open the "Resources" folder of the project. It contains the generated code - and this is where you need to set your breakpoints. I am using Studio 3.5.1 and it seems that if you set the breakpoint in the controller it will now stop at that breakpoint - but for CommonJS modules I need to do it in Resources. You can "unhide" the Resources folder in your normal navigation to make it easier to set the breakpoints.

/John